# C# MonoGame OpenGL reading in a file and loading textures onto the frame

Tags: c#, opengl, monogame

I'm using MonoGame on C# with the OpenGL application.

I'm making a tower defense game and I want to load in a map that looks like this:

```
++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++
$###++++++++++++++++
+++#+++++++######+++
+++#+++++++#++++#+++
+++#++++####++++##++
+++#++++#++++++++#++
+++#++++#####++++#++
+++#++++++++#++++#++
+++#++++++++#++++#++
+++#++++#####++++#++
+++#++++#++++++++#++
+++#++++#++++++++#++
+++#++++#++++++++#++
+++######++++++++#++
+++++++++++++++++#++
+++++++++++++++++#++
+++++++++#########++
+++++++++#++++++++++
+++++++++&++++++++++

Key:
$  = start
# = path
& = finish
+ = grass area
```

By reading in a file, I want to read in for these keys and place a tile down at a specified location.
I did the following in C# Visual Studio that works

```
public partial class Game : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
{
    #region Variables
    private Wave _GameWave;
    public Wave GameWave
    {
        get { return _GameWave; }
        set { _GameWave = value; }
    }

    private Map _GameMap;
    public Map GameMap
    {
        get { return _GameMap; }
        set { _GameMap = value; }
    }

    private System.Timers.Timer _GameLoop;
    public System.Timers.Timer GameLoop
    {
        get { return _GameLoop; }
        set { _GameLoop = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    public Game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GameLoop = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        GameWave = new Wave();
        CreateMap();
        Image I = new Image();
        I.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\Pictures\RawModels\GreenMonster.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Grid.SetColumn(I, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(I, 2);
        GameGrid.Children.Add(I);
    }

private void CreateMap()
    {
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
        GameMap = new Map();
        for (int x = 0; x < GameMap.ActualWidth; x++)
        {
            GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < GameMap.ActualHeight; y++)
        {
            GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < GameMap.ActualHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < GameMap.ActualWidth; x++)
            {

                Image I = new Image();
                if (GameMap.MapArray[x, y].CanPlaceTower)
                {  
                    I.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\Pictures\Squares\Grass.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                }
                else
                {
                    I.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\Pictures\Squares\Path.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                }
                I.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                Grid.SetColumn(I, x);
                Grid.SetRow(I, y);
                GameGrid.Children.Add(I);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to do the same thing or similar in MonoGame, I can't figure out a way.

I have this so far
    base.Draw(gameTime);

```
        //Drawing and rendering out the image
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        for (int y = 0; y < WindowWidth; y+=64)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < WindowWidth; x+=64)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(grass, new Rectangle(x, y, 64, 64), Color.White);
            }
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you are wondering how to read in a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you basically want to use TitleContainer.OpenStream to read in a text file.

Something like this:

```
var path = @"Content\YourData.txt";

using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(path))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();

        // do your thing
    }
}
```